# Watch for async external DOM changes in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I am injecting ads from Revive Adserver with this component:

```
<template>
 <div class="ins-box">
  <ins ref="insEl" :data-revive-zoneid="zoneId" data-revive-id="hash"></ins>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    zoneId: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
}
```

The external api from Revive Adserver will load the ad image for the zone (in the example zone 1234), converting the `<ins>` element:

```
<ins zone-id="1234" />
```

The `<img>` tag it creates looks something like this:

```
<ins data-v-fdd5803a="" data-revive-zoneid="7859">
 <a href="http://servedby.revive-adserver.net/ck.php?params" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.source.com/image-555.jpg" width="468" height="60" alt="" title="" border="0">
 </a>
</ins>
```

I would like to edit the created `<img>` element when it is added into the DOM. I would need to remove the width and height values.

In jQuery I could do something like `$('ins img').load(function() {})`

What is the Vue way to do this?
The element is not created by my Vue code and I don't have reference to it. On top of that the there might come a new `<img>` element now and them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this with pure CSS, for example using an attribute selector.  Setting the image's height and width to `auto` should be the equivalent of removing the HTML attributes.

Here's an example that will style all images inside `<a>` tags having an `href` with the ad server domain.

```css
a[href*="revive-adserver.net"] img{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

---

If you insist on doing this with JavaScript, use a [`mutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the element's parent to detect external DOM changes to its children. Give the parent a ref:

```html
<div ref="ins-box" class="ins-box">
```

Create the mutation observer:

```js
mounted() {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    const img = this.$refs['ins-box'].querySelector('img');
    img.onload = () => {
      // Now do something with `img`
    }
  });
  observer.observe(this.$refs['ins-box'], { childList: true });
}
```

The reason for watching for changes on the parent instead of the element itself is the element might be completely replaced by the external service.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves my issue (ignoring height and width). I had scoped css and that didn't work for the img tag but removing the scoping helped. But, if I would have to do something with the javascript to the img tag. Where would you put it? I'll update my question for this.

Comment: You could improve your css part of the question by mentioning that the Vue's scoped style does not work for the DOM elements added by the external script. That information would've helped me with my problem, earlier.

Comment: I wouldn't mind adding that but I'm not sure that's always accurate considering that a deep selector might work perfectly well, I haven't tested it.  Keep in mind that scoped styles comes up on many Vue + css questions, and there are answers on the site dedicated to that topic.  It would at least double the size of every answer to fully cover scoped css, which could detract from the core of the answer.  Maybe I can include a parenthetical "(take note of scoped styles)" sort of edit with a link.